# Tera Term Language: wait doesn't wait for timeout to end

Tags: timeout, wait, ttl, tera

I'm trying to write a macro to speed up the setting up of a test.

What I have to do is sending a bunch of config commands to my board, and wait for a 'ok' after each one. The last command is the one that starts the test, and after that I want to wait up to 30 seconds for a certain answer. The problem is that even if I set up a timeout, all commands are sent one after another without waiting for the timeout and the test ends as soon as it starts. Am I missing something?

Here is my code:

```
send 'command 1'

timeout = 5             ;timeout set to 5 seconds
wait 'ok'

send 'command 2'

timeout = 5             ;timeout set to 5 seconds
wait 'ok'

send 'command 3'

timeout = 5             ;timeout set to 5 seconds
wait 'ok'

send 'command 4'

timeout = 5             ;timeout set to 5 seconds
wait 'ok'

send 'command 5'

timeout = 5             ;timeout set to 5 seconds
wait 'ok'

send 'command 6'

timeout = 5             ;timeout set to 5 seconds
wait 'ok'

send 'test start'

timeout = 30                ;timeout set to 30 seconds
wait 'the response I want'

if result = 1 goto pass
if result = 0 goto fail
```

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled over your question while looking for a different issue.

Timeout is used to say "If thing has not been done in X time, continue" and only needs to be set once. You also want to set it before you send your commands.

In your case it would be

```
Timeout = 5
Send 'Command'
Wait 'OK'
Send 'Command'
Wait 'OK'
Timeout = 30
Send 'Command'
Wait 'OK'
```

You might also want to add a slight pause between them with MPause to keep them from stumbling over each other like old modems tend to do.

```
Send 'Command'
Wait 'OK'
MPause 50
Send 'Command'
Wait 'OK'
```

Depending on what your doing it might also be worth changing the Sends and Waits to SendLn and WaitLn, these will send a new line with the commands and wait for a response with a new line, and it's pretty common.

Warning though, TeraTerm is a bit of a buggy mess and is a bit limited. If you can use a real language I'd do so.